# Open ssh error: packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, ssh, sftp

First i am going to explain what I'm trying to do. I have set up a webserver running ubuntu server on top of vmware-esxi. I want to use SFTP over SSH to upload my website's code. We did this in a php class I took.

I followed this [guide](https://baxeico.wordpress.com/2015/12/07/configure-sftp-access-to-your-ubuntu-server-through-ssh/).

So I have a user named sftpuser and a group called sftp and when I try to connect it gives the error:

```
packet_write_wait: Connection to x.x.x.x port 22: Broken pipe
```

My ssh config looks this at the bottom, the rest is unchanged

```
ClientAliveInterval 20
ClientAliveCountMax 5

TCPKeepAlive yes

Match group sftp
ChrootDirectory %h
X11Forwarding no
AllowTcpForwarding no
ForceCommand internal-sftp
```

I'm new to linux so I'm unsure what the cause could be. Thanks.

Edit:

The error in /var/log/auth.log is

```
fatal: bad ownership of chroot directory component "/var/www"
```

Comment: Can you give the content of /var/log/auth.log from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok the issue seems to be I did not have permissions for /var/www, when I changed the permissions as shown in the guide I did that for /var/www/html. So when I ran this

```
cd /var/www
chown root:sftp .
chmod 755 .
chown -R sftpuser:sftp *
```

it worked. I also ran it again on /var/www/html just to be sure.